# How to write on top of pandas HDF5 'read-only mode' files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I am storing data using pandas built-in HDF5 methods.

Somehow, these HDF5 files were turned into 'read-only' files, and I am getting a lot of `Opening xxx in read-only mode` messages when I open those files in write mode and **I can't write them**, which is something I really need to do.

The thing I really don't understand so far is how come those files turned into read-only, as I am not aware of a piece of code that I wrote that may result in that behavior. *(I have tried to check if the data stored in the HDF5 is corrupt, but I am able to read it and manipulate it, so it seems to be working just fine)*

**I have 2 questions:**

1. How can I append data to those 'read-only mode' HDF5 files? (Can I convert them back to write mode or any other clever solution?)
2. Is there any pandas method that would change the HDF5 file to a 'read-only mode' by default so I can avoid turning those files into read-only in the first place?

**Code:**

The piece of code that is raising this issue is, which is the piece I use to save the output I generated:

```
    with pd.HDFStore('data/observer/' + self._currency + '_' + str(ts)) as hdf:

        hdf.append(key='observers', value=df, format='table', data_columns=True)
```

I also use this piece of code to manipulate the outputs that were generated previously:

```
    for the_file in list_dir:
        if currency in the_file:
            temp_df = pd.read_hdf(folder + the_file)
            ...
```

I use some select commands as well to get specific columns from the data files:

```
    with pd.HDFStore('data/observer/' + self.currency + '_' + timestamp) as hdf:
        df = hdf.select(key='observers', columns=[x, y])
```

**Error Traceback:**

```
File ".../data_processing/observer_data.py", line 52, in save_obs_to_pandas
hdf.append(key='observers', value=df, format='table', data_columns=True)
File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 963, in append
**kwargs)
File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1341, in _write_to_group
s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3930, in write
self.set_info()
File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3163, in set_info
self.attrs.info = self.info
File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/attributeset.py", line 464, in __setattr__
nodefile._check_writable()
File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 2119, in _check_writable
raise FileModeError("the file is not writable")
tables.exceptions.FileModeError: the file is not writable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../general_manager.py", line 144, in <module>
gm.run()
File ".../general_manager.py", line 114, in run
list_of_observer_managers = self.load_all_observer_managers()
File ".../general_manager.py", line 64, in load_all_observer_managers
observer = currency_pool.map(self.load_observer_manager, list_of_currencies)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
raise self._value
tables.exceptions.FileModeError: the file is not writable
```

Comment: (I do use HDF5 but with h5py/numpy). Do you have some small example of code? In principle I don't think the HDF5 format support making the file read-only, but you can choose to open in it read-only mode. See e.g. the [documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/FmSource/08_TheFile_favicon_test.html). But really, we could learn more from your code.

Comment: a potential answer will depend on the way how you work with HDF5 files. Please add your code to the question

Comment: could you also add an error traceback?

Comment: @MaxU I have reviewed my code, and posted what I identified as the different kinds of operations I do with the HDF5 files. It is actually quite a bit of code, so something may be missing. If I find something new, I will update you. Thanks for the support :)

Comment: @MaxU, I am pretty sure it is an OS issue. I have ran some of the simulations as the root user. I am changing file permissions and testing it right now.

Comment: @MaxU, I messed up with file permissions, hence the issue. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue at hand was that I messed up with OS file permissions. The file I was trying to read belonged to the `root` (as I had run the code that generated those files with the root) and I was trying to access them with a `user` account.

I am running debian, and the following command (as `root`) solved my issues:

```
chown -R user.user folder
```

This commands recursively changes permissions of all files inside that folder to `user.user`.